# The ODP.NET in ODAC 11.2 Release 3 (11.2.0.2.1) already supports Entity Framework (EF)?

Tags: .net, asp.net, oracle, entity-framework, odp.net

The last release os ODP.NET already supports Entity Framework?
Someone uses it?
If the answer is YES. How about it? Any issues?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [What's New](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/whatsnew/index.html) page says it doesn't

> **ODAC 11.2 Release 3 (11.2.0.2.1) for Microsoft Windows 32-bit and x64 Released**
>   ODAC 11.2 Release 3 includes new .NET support for TimesTen In-Memory Database, 64-bit xcopy deployment, and 64-bit .NET Framework 4. This release does not contain Entity Framework features, which will be forthcoming in a separate ODAC beta.

but I haven't tried it myself.

Comment: Thanks, i searched, but not find this information in oracle.com

Comment: So, they was released a beta on 10, february. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/whatsnew/index.html

Answer (score 4):

No, ODAC 11.2 Release 3 (11.2.0.2.1) does not support EF.

There will be a beta out soon and it will be clearly labeled as supporting EF.

Edit: 11.2.0.3 production is out now and it supports Entity Framework.

Christian Shay
Oracle

Comment: More important, does it support Code-first yet?

Comment: As of this date, 11/26/2012, ODP.NET does not support Code First. Keep an eye on http://otn.oracle.com/dotnet for new release announcements. Christian Shay - Oracle

Comment: I've been talking to Alex Keh a bit by email about a quasi model-first/code-first approach. If you have a moment and/or interest, you can get my email from him. Aside from help, I'd like to offer the ODP.Net team my discoveries/test results in return.

Answer (score 2):

Yes,
I've used it. It seems great but there are some problems:
1- it does not support Identity columns (it is not updated after insert)
2- complex foreign keys is not supported:
   Users(ID, AppID, ...) PK is (ID, AppID)
   Roles(ID, AppID, ...) PK is (ID, AppID)
   UserRoles(AppID, UserID, RoleID) which
         (AppID, UserID) is FK to Users
         (AppID, RoleID) is FK to Roles
3- Very slow to retrieve model from DB or update it. some times you may see some inconsistency if you change your model.

I didn't tested it for performance issues but knowing that they've converted the open-source project efprovider it may have some problems in performance (but honestly i didn't see any).

Comment: I need to correct inaccuracies here: 1) Identity columns are supported, however in Oracle these are called "Triggers with Sequences". You need to modify the edmx file to add the StoredGeneratedPattern entry manually due to a VS 2010 bug (which is only fixed in a hotfix) 2) I have heard about the issue of complex foreign keys so I can't speak to that one 3) There was a problem in the beta at the time of your writing that resulted in slow performance, but that is fixed in the current production release. Christian Shay, Oracle

Comment: @ChristianShay it helped to hear about the triggers with sequences issue. it is no longer necessary to edit the XML itself, the Generation Pattern can be set via the UI properties.

Comment: @In Vs2010 you need the hotfix, or the UI property has no effect. Surely fixed in vs2012, although I haven't tried it.